# Siri stopped working

Tags: siri, iphone

Since iOS 8.1 Siri stopped working for me. The sound and wave animation appear, but it seems the microphone does not register my speech, or it is not processed by Siri.

I have read various "solutions" and tried to troubleshoot it, but I am running out of ideas.

I have tried, turning Siri on and off again :), restarting the phone and resetting different settings (including the network settings). Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas, how can I resolve this?

Comment: If the 'wave' actually 'waves' then it's hearing the mic. Does it move or remain a static line?

Comment: How dit you restart your phone, pressing both power and home button or only the power button?

Comment: @Tetsujin it moves but it is very synchronous movement. It doesn't seem to change the amplitude while I am speaking. In other words it is never a static line, when I stop talking.

Comment: @Jules I have tried both.

Comment: I'd go for a full backup/restore

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and will let you know. I thought that was the only option left.

Comment: You could try to restore your network settings in settings > general, also check if your microphone is working

Comment: @Jules Thanks, but as I have written, I already have reseted the network settings. The microphone must be working, because I can talk on the phone normally.

Comment: It's working again as of iOS 11, so it seems it was a software issue

Answer (score 1):

I have iPhone 5s and iOS 8.3 and my siri stopped working after replacing broken glass. My current workaround is to use the headphone microphone.

I think iPhone when using SIRI does some sophisticated background noise reduction. For that it uses additional microphones I think for iPhone 5s and up there are three all together.

Try to use the iPhone supplied Headset microphone I am certain this will work for you. This is my current workaround and it works all the time..

Comment: You are right, it works with the headphones. Didn't know that. However, this does not fix the problem. Do you have an idea? I googled a bit, but people don't seem to have found a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a microphone problem. Test it by recording a video of using the front facing camera. If you can hear yourself then it's probably a software issue but if there is no noise then it's probably a hardware problem with the front facing microphone

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Video recording, talking on the phone, etc. works normally. I think it is a mix between a hardware and a software issue, as Siri works with the headphones, but not without them. A full restore did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The Siri mic is the one that is used during speakerphone operation, and not the one that is used during normal talking on the phone operation.

Try calling someone and changing to speakerphone.  If they cannot hear you, then the problem lies with that microphone.

What model iphone do you have?  On iPhone 6 (and up I believe) there is a very small microphone to the left of the phone-speaker (the end that you would hold up to your ear when talking on the phone normally).

Comment: It was a software issue. It started working again with iOS 11.

Before that people could hear me when I was speaking on speakerphone, but Siri was not working. It is an iPhone 6.

Answer (score -1):

Reset all settings and then do a hard reboot by holding home and power buttons. This fixed it for me